# Passing Subclass Type to Java Generic Method with reflection throws no Exception

Tags: java, generics, reflection, java-8

So I was experiencing a weird bug in Spring where an abstract controller method was being called and being passed an object that the type system should not have allowed.

This is a simple example that demonstrates the bug.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class RandomJavaTesting
{
    public static class Animal {
    }

    public static class Cat extends Animal {
    }

    public static class AnimalManager<T extends Animal> {

        // This gets called and doesn't blow up
        public void add(T animal){
            // This will throw a class cast exception
            // Why does this blow up here for CatManager?
            this.callAdd(animal);
        }

        public void callAdd(T animal){

        }
    }

    public static class CatManager extends AnimalManager<Cat> {

        @Override
        public void callAdd(Cat animal)
        {
            // This will never run
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void callingGenericMethodWithSubClassType() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException
    {

        CatManager manager = new CatManager();
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        AnimalManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("add", Animal.class).invoke(manager, animal);

    }
}
```

This test gives the following exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at RandomJavaTesting.callingGenericMethodWithSubClassType(RandomJavaTesting.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: RandomJavaTesting$Animal cannot be cast to RandomJavaTesting$Cat
        at RandomJavaTesting$CatManager.callAdd(RandomJavaTesting.java:28)
        at RandomJavaTesting$AnimalManager.add(RandomJavaTesting.java:20)
        ... 32 more
```

Basically, my question is, why does calling the `add` method not cause a ClassCastException.
Why does calling `callAdd` cause the exception?
I understand that generic information isn't preserved at runtime however I was under the assumption that extending a class caused the type parameters of a generic class to be preserved.
This is the mechanisim behind the [Guava TypeToken](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken). Or, at least that's what I thought.

Comment: After type erasure, the signature of the `add` method is `public void add(Animal animal)`. The `CatManager` inherits that method, and not a `public void add(Cat animal)`. Therefore, `addCall` is the only method which requires a `Cat` since it was overridden with that signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in that the generic super type is preserved but you are overestimating the implications. It just implies that Reflection methods like [`Class.getGenericSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--) will provide you with the information, which is indeed the mechanisim behind the Guava TypeToken.

The inherited methods are still subject to type erasure. By the way, if you pass objects of a wrong type to `Method.invoke`, you don’t get a `ClassCastException`, but an `IllegalArgumentException`. But, of course, it would be confusing if you perform a reflective query for the method `AnimalManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("add", Animal.class)` and end up at a method having a signature other than `add(Animal)`.

This even applies to the scenario where you override the method, e.g. when you use `AnimalManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("callAdd", Animal.class).invoke(manager, animal);`, you still don’t get an `IllegalArgumentException`, instead, a method `addAll(Animal)` is invoked which produces a `ClassCastException` when trying to delegate to the explicitly defined method `addAll(Cat)`. The `addAll(Animal)` method involved in this process is called *bridge method*.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it broke the Liskov’s Substitution Principle.

For add method you can consider type T as Animal, but for addAll method the type is specified as Cat, so you couldn't replace type Cat with type Animal.

Comment: No, you can not “consider type T as Animal”. For the generic type system, the class `CatManager` is a subtype of `AnimalManager<Cat>` and `AnimalManager<Cat>` does not have a method `add(Animal)`. It only has a method `add(Cat)`, which `CatManager` inherits. The problem is that there is no Reflection operation for querying `AnimalManager<Cat>` for its `add` method. Instead, `AnimalManager.class` reflects the *raw type* `AnimalManager` which subverts the generic type system.